# Stopping OSX from moving windows from second monitor

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, imac

I have a HDTV as my second monitor. I move windows to that monitor. When the computer and the TV sleeps and I bring both back, on the brief time both are initializing, OSX thinks the monitor is not there and moves all windows to where on that monitor the main monitor.

I didn't have this problem on the past when I had an old iMac and used RGB to connect the computer to the TV but now I have a new iMac and I am using the HDMI port. The "intelligence" of the HDMI output compared to the dumbness of the RGB is making things worst.

Any way to prevent stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any way to prevent stop this?*

**Not feasibly or at least, not cleanly, for your use case.**

You would need to make a fairly low level change in how OSX runs its graphical environment or window manager (Quartz). And considering who made that, you won't be able to get in there without Matrix agents busting down your door and complaining tirelessly.

If you still insist on pwning OSX in to doing this, the people [over here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/) are rather skilled at using OSX to its full potential.